# Splunk doesnt return all the results - using rest API -

Tags: java, json, splunk, splunk-query

I'm retrieving data from Splunk using rest API via production port 8980, on the GUI I can see 770 events when I retrieve data I got less then a 100.

here is my code in Java to retrieve data:

```
public JSONObject Post_request() throws IOException, ParseException {
        String Query = "search " + OS_Vuln_Query;
        Job job = session.make_Request().getJobs().create(Query);
        while (!job.isDone()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        JobResultsArgs resultsArgs = new JobResultsArgs();
        resultsArgs.setOutputMode(JobResultsArgs.OutputMode.JSON);
        InputStream results = job.getResults(resultsArgs);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(results));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(sb.toString());
        String vulns_as_string = json.get("results").toString();
        JSONArray vulns_to_json = (JSONArray) parser.parse(vulns_as_string);
        if (vulns_to_json.size()>0)
        {
            System.out.print("Splunk return results");
            for (int v = 0; v < vulns_to_json.size(); v++)
            {
                String vuln_as_string = vulns_to_json.get(v).toString();
                Vulnerability vulnerability = new Gson().fromJson(vuln_as_string, Vulnerability.class);
                data_Parsed = true;
                vulnerability.ports_to_List();
                list_of_OS_Vulnerability.add(vulnerability);
            }
            return json;
        }
        System.out.print("Splunk return empty results");
        return  null;
    }
```

I make request to Splunk from different class - it return service which I used to pass queries to splunk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure it out from Splunk Documentation, wasn't really in the beginning. 
resultsargs if not set to 0 will return the first 100 results only.
to fix that just set setcount in resultsArgs to 0:

```
        resultsArgs.setCount(0); // to return all results
```